# Can I run ASP.Net application with only aspx and cs file?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Sorry friends, I know this is silly question, but I want to know that can I run asp.net application with only aspx and cs file? The dll are also not generated for the application and Web.config file is also not present.

If there is any solution for above question then how can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the question you asked, the answer is No you can't, but by opening it as the website(refer answers below) you can do that. Eventually the bin and the web.config will be generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can open it as a Web Site.

File => Open => Web Site => File system => [Select the folder where the files are located]

In terms of Visual Studio, Web Sites are folder based projects - there is no project file

You can read more here: [Web Application Projects versus Web Site Projects in Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Open it as a website project. In VS websites are folder based projects, so there is no project files.

File->Open->Website->File system->Select a folder to put your files

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. When buidling your solution, the class is compiled into a dll, contained in the bin folder, which has to be embedded in your application.